# NullpointerException in JOptionPane

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, joptionpane

****It throws NullPointerException in JOptionPane code as following.****

```
public static void main(String[]args){


    String[] options={"Do it again?", "Exit"};
    int response=0;
    int indexOfZip;
    do{
        try{

        String dataStr=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a zip code");


        if(dataStr!=null){
             while (k<i){
                 if (place[k].equals(dataStr)){

                 indexOfZip=k;
                     k++;
                 }

             }
             int data=Integer.parseInt(dataStr);
             response=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                           "You asked me to search for zip code:"+dataStr+"The zip code "+dataStr+" belongs to"+place[k].getTown()+","+place[k].getState()+"Do you want me to search again?",
                           "results",

                           JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                           JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                           null,
                           options,options[0]);


             System.out.println("You asked me to search for zip code:"+dataStr);
             System.out.println("The zip code "+dataStr+" belongs to"+place[k].getTown()+","+place[k].getState());
             System.out.println("Do you want me to search again?");

        }


        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bad Numeric String, try again.", "Input Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

         }
    }while(response==0);
    if (response!=0){
       System.out.print("No");
       System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    }



    }
```

The terminal says the exception is for this line
    response=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,

But I cannot see anything wrong here, because the "response" is initialized before.

Comment: What's `place=[k]`? Is it null? If not, are its fields null? Post your full stacktrace and double check that you're looking at the correct involved line. Do null tests **before** the involved line to see what's null, and then figure out why.

Comment: @PavelUvarov Sorry i m new to code.  Where am i supposed to declare indexOfZip?

Comment: It depends on fact - where you use it. Now it has no usages, so this variable can be simply omitted. But according to other sources part I see some variables that weren't declared, but used. For example - `i`. Common way to decide where you should place variable - is decide on 2 characteristics of visibility - it should be not less than sufficient, but not more than required. Additionally code styles defines that for methods is not recommended to be bigger than 10-12 lines. And it is not recommended to have more than 2 levels of nesting blocks in methods. I recommend you read some code styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `place[k]` must be `null`,
and `place[k].getTown()` triggers `NullPointerException`.
Watch the value of `place[k]` in a debugger (or add a print statement).

Comment: Do you know what ?? `place[k]` is a String. How come String have those methods ?

Comment: We don't see the declaration of `place`, so we don't know what it is. If it's a string than we're looking at non-compiling code and all bets are off.

Comment: I see. I forgot to call the method of place[k]. Now I change the code to  if (place[k].getZip().equals(dataStr)){
    
     indexOfZip=k;
            k++;
        }    but it still has the same exception ...

Comment: Looks like `place[k]` is `null`. You can't call anything on it while it's `null`.